# Creating a basic trigger

Tags: 7

After installing Drupal 7, I created 2 files (beep.module and beep.info).

```
/**
 * @file
 * Provide a simulated beep.
 */
function beep_beep() {
  watchdog('beep', 'Beep!');
}

/*
 * Implementation of hook_action_info().
 */ 
function beep_action_info () {
  return array(
    'beep_beep_action' => array(
      'type' => 'system',
      'label' => t('Beep annoyingly'),
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers' => array('node_view', 'node_insert', 'node_update', 'node_delete'),
    ),
    'beep_multiple_beep_action' => array(
      'type' => 'system',
      'label' => t('Beep multiple times'),
      'configurable' => TRUE,
      'triggers' => array('node_view', 'node_insert', 'node_update', 'node_delete'),
    ),
  );
}



/**
 * Simulate a beep. A Drupal action.
 */
function beep_beep_action() {
  beep_beep();
}
```

```
name = Beep
description = Simulates a system beep.
package = Pro Drupal Development
core = 7.x
files[] = beep.module
```

In http://localhost/drupal/?q=admin/structure/trigger/node I see "Beep annoyingly," but not 
"Beep multiple times."

Can anyone point out what I can doto see both?

Comment: I see youhave a callback function `beep_beep_action() ` but no `beep_multiple_beep_action()` have you forgotten it ?

Comment: @tostinni no actually it is given in book like that only.Thanks for your pointer I have been able to get past through this one.

Comment: So my comment answered your question ?

Comment: @tostinni yes yyyyy

Comment: Ok I added an answer in order to solve this question ;)

Comment: The Pro Drupal7 Development book by todd tomlinson?  it has A LOT of mistakes, especially in the examples.

Comment: Yes, plenty of even relatively simple ones.

Answer (score 2):

I see youhave a callback function `beep_beep_action()` but no `beep_multiple_beep_action()` have you forgotten it ?

Comment: I've been through the same problem (the code's from "Pro Drupal 7 Development"), and that it the problem.